# How to upgrade From Doctrine 1 to Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine-1.2

I'm using Doctrine 1 with Zend framework, and I have to upgrade from Doctrine 1 to Doctrine 2 to use Data mapper instead of active record design patterns.

Is there anyway or instructions to do it?

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be a task that convert old doctrine 1 schema into annoted php classes:

```
doctrine orm:convert-d1-schema
```

I will let you read [this short tutorial](https://dzone.com/articles/doctrine-1-doctrine-2) on how to do that.

Basically:

- you need to convert schema to annoted php classes (with the command above)
- convert your file in your application to use the data mapper